# Reindex and update join field

Tags: elasticsearch

**INTRO**

I have `IndexA` without any `join` fields, and I would like to add one.

For this purpose I've created `IndexB` with extended mapping, which includes a new field. I'm trying to reindex `IndexA` into `IndexB`

**QUESTION**

How do I update every document in the `IndexB` to become a parent through the reindexing?

*In [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/parent-join.html) example, in order to make a document parent one has to set the join field like this:*

```
"my_join_field": {
  "name": "question" 
}
```

*`question` is the parent type in the defined relationship*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "IndexA"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "IndexB",
    "routing": "=1"
  },
   "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.my_join_field = params.j",
    "params": {
         "j": {
            "name" : "parent_relationship_name"
         }
      },
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```